# Vtune profile result show a significant portion of CPU time is spinning

Tags: c++, intel-vtune

I am using **Vtune Threading mode** to profile my project which running on windows 10. At Top-down view, I found 39.1% cpu time spend on spinning, callstack show in below picture.

[image: Top-down view]

But in **Platform View**, I find the spinning callstack only cost 40us per frame, in my project on frame cost about 7~14ms,

[image: Platform View 1]

[image: Platform View 2]

1.Whether I need to pay attention to the spin time of WaitForSingleObject, if i want to optimize running speed of my project

2.Why Top-down view show ApexScene::simulate spinning cost 39.1% Cup time ,but ApexScene::simulate callstack only cost 3%~6% cpu time each
frame at Platform View

As far as I can see, WaitForSingleObject make thread enter kernel mode, which cost a large amount of cpu time, but thread will not spinning when there is not signal

Comment: Can you please provide "minimal reproducible" (example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can try reproducing your issue from our end?
On which version of Vtune you are trying?

Comment: I find that Vtune spin time inaccurate. Same environment, same program, when I set CPU sampling interval 10ms, I get 57.5% spin time; but when set CPU sampling interval 1ms, I get 29.1% spin time. If I use Hardware Event-Based mode, there ara 6.6% spin time.

Comment: To test which mode is accurate, I write one test progam, looping WaitForSingleObject function， and hook WaitForSingleObject calculate execution time，the conclusion is that spin time from Hardware Event-Based mode same as my result